# How do I change the colors of most draw.io icons?

Tags: app.diagrams.net, formatting

All I can find is documentation for changing "SVG" file colors on this page:
https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/svg-edit-colours

But most of the icons in the shapes library are not svg files, but images. (And there is no way to search the libraries for only configurable icons).

Do I have to create a new file and change its color and add to my own library? (That's a heck of a lot of work for entire icon sets). I keep thinking I must be missing something. If someone could explain this, I bet more of us mortals could get a lot more out from this product.

I want to change the color of an image icon like this,[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the shapes you want to the document, highlight those that should have the same color, click "Style" (in the format panel on the right) and set the color. Then add them to your "Scratchpad" by clicking the "+". That's how I did it. Took less than five minutes, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Sorry for the 8 month delay. I was very ill.  That method above works for some shapes, but not icons based on PNG  files, which many in the app are.  I can find no mention of these anywhere.  For example if a magnifying glass icon is powder blue, and I want to change it to black, it's simply not discussed anywhere. 

Can anyone help here?

Comment: No problem. Glad you're feeling better! HM, we might be using different shape libraries. I tested a bunch of random icons from different libraries and I was able to change color of them all. There are versions of both of the icons you have mentioned in the "iOS Icons" library. If you don't already have it, you can add it by clicking + More Shapes (lower left corner) >Software>check iOS>Apply.

Comment: Using IOS icons did the trick. Though using the material-core or essential icons it does not work.